# Randomly created VMs in VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

i just opened my Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager and i saw that there were 8 randomly created VM's with strange naming. I am 100% sure that i didn't create them. So, how can this happen? I googled for this kind of problem but i didn't find anything helpful.
[These are the VM's that i didn't create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJKHq.png)

I need some Advice from you. If it's not plausible how this can happen, i will have to reset my PC i guess.

Thanks in advance for any tips and advice!

I had created 2 Vm's and wanted to do some testing with NGINX and Terraform. These VM's are randomly created and i don't know why and how?